# Javascript how to create properly DateObject from datetime string?

Tags: javascript, string, datetime

I have datetime as string, fxp:

```
2014-11-10 12:12
```

And I need create from this string Date object with correctly set months (in object months starting from 0).

So i tried this:

```
 var d = Date.parse("2014-11-10 12:12");
```

But it seems to be not working.

```
 console.log("Month is " + d.getMonth());
```

Is not giving result.

How can i parse and create date object from string correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I always link anybody dealing with date parsing in js to this library. http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.parse`  method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

You cant parse the Month from that value. You have to use a new Date object.

Try:

```
var d = new Date("2014-11-10 12:12");
console.log("Month is " + d.getMonth());
```